# Update Java Dependency from Fat Jar to Thin Jahr

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I'm currently working with Talend Studio, and in one of our projects, we need to update the netty-all library from version 4.1.68 to 4.1.96. After importing the newer jar file, we discovered that version 4.1.96 is significantly smaller than the previous one. Consequently, we encountered a series of ClassNotFoundException errors.

To resolve these issues, we had to manually import several specific Netty dependencies, such as netty-transport and netty-resolver. This approach feels cumbersome, and I'm wondering if there might be a more efficient way to handle this update.

Specifically, I have two questions:

Is there a method to generate a netty-all 4.1.96 jar file that includes all necessary dependencies (a fat jar)?
If the above solution is not feasible or optimal, what alternative approaches could be more efficient for updating the Netty library in our Talend Studio project?
Any guidance or insights from those experienced with Netty and Talend Studio would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You should share the actual dependencies you are using so others can understand what artifacts exactly are you using.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the targ.gz file from here -
https://netty.io/downloads.html.

Inside the "all" folder edit the pom.xml by adding this snippet in the `plugins` section -

```
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

and then run -

```
mvn clean package
```

The jar you need will be created inside `all/target`. It'll have a prefix like *`-all-dependencies.jar`.